# XDebug is not loaded in PHP (Vista, Apache Module)

Tags: php, windows, apache, windows-vista, xdebug

I downloaded php_xdebug-2.0.5-5.3-vc9.dll, added at the end of PHP.ini the following line:

```
zend_extension_ts="C:/Program Files/php5/ext/php_xdebug-2.0.5-5.3-vc9.dll"
```

When I use phpinfo(), xdebug is not loaded.

When I run command "php.exe -m", it not loaded as well.

How can this be resolved?

My configuration: PHP 5.3.1, Apache 2.2.14 with Apache Module, OS: Windows Vista
Both php and xdebug are thread safe.

This is somewhat similar with: 
[Apache not loading Xdebug, but does when started from the Command Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207489/apache-not-loading-xdebug-but-does-when-started-from-the-command-line)

**EDIT:**

I use VC6 dll and fixed configuration:

```
zend_extension="C:/Program Files/php5/ext/php_xdebug-2.0.5-5.3-vc6.dll"
```

Still can not find xdebug in phpinfo() output.

Answer (score 7):

`zend_extension_ts` is deprecated on >5.3.  Try it with `zend_extension` instead.

Comment: This worked for me, even though the PHP installed (along with XAMPP is thread safe one) - VC11 X86 32bit thread safe. Strange

Answer (score 4):

use zend_extension instead of zend_extension_ts

and look carefuly 
"Compiler" , "Thread Safety" , "Architecture" and PHP Version
parameters in phpinfo()

example my php info say

PHP Version 5.3.1

Compiler    MSVC6 (Visual C++ 6.0)

Architecture    x86

Thread Safety   enabled

so i used Xdebug 2.1.0 / 5.3 VC6 (32 bit)

Answer (score 1):

You should probably not use the `VC9` version, but the `VC6`.

For more informations, see the block "**Which version do I choose?**" in the left-sidebar of http://windows.php.net/ which states *(quoting)* :

> If you are using PHP with Apache 1 or
>   Apache2 from apache.org you need to
>   use the VC6 versions of PHP
>
> If you are using PHP with IIS you
>   should use the VC9 versions of PHP
>
> Do NOT use VC9 version with apache.org
>   binaries

Also, quoting the [Installation page of Xdebug's documentation](http://xdebug.org/docs/install) :

> From PHP 5.3 onwards, you always need
>   to use `zend_extension` and not
>   `zend_extension_ts`.

Comment: I used php 5.3.1 by VC9. Now I tried to set up php 5.3.2 by VC6 and apache crashes on startup. PHP 5.3.1 is not available for download any more, strange!

I tried dll for VC6 only but it does not help...

Comment: From reading the release notes, it appears that Xdebug 2.0.5 has some compatibility issues with PHP 5.3.  I realize 2.1.0 is still in beta, but you might try it to see if it fixes whatever is causing the crashing.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same problem on Windows 7 too. It didn't work for me but perhaps for you it does. Xdebug has a special service page which helps you find out which version to download and what steps to take: http://www.xdebug.org/find-binary.php.

Following this didn't work for me unfortunatly. When I perform 'php -m' xdebug does not appear in the loaded modules list.

Comment: I suspect the latest xdebug is not working with PHP 5.3.5 - have tried everything but can't get it working...

Answer (score 1):

perform **php --ini** to check witch config file is loaded.
if you have something like this :

**Loaded Configuration File:         (none)**
**Scan for additional .ini files in: (none)**
**Additional .ini files parsed:      (none)**

Just copy your **php.ini** in **windows** directory ;)