# Failed to Install Xdebug

Tags: php, xdebug

've registered xdebug in php.ini (as per http://xdebug.org/docs/install) but it's not showing up when i run "php -m" or when i get a test page to run "phpinfo()". I've just installed the latest version of XAMPP. I've used both "zend_extention" and "zend_extention_ts" to specify the path of the xdebug dll. I ensured that my apache server restarted and used the latest change of my php.ini by executing "httpd -k restart".

Can anyone provide any suggestions in getting xdebug to show up?

Here are the contents of my php.ini file.
    [PHP]

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; About php.ini   ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; PHP's initialization file, generally called php.ini, is responsible for
; configuring many of the aspects of PHP's behavior.

; PHP attempts to find and load this configuration from a number of locations.
; The following is a summary of its search order:
; 1. SAPI module specific location.
; 2. The PHPRC environment variable. (As of PHP 5.2.0)
; 3. A number of predefined registry keys on Windows (As of PHP 5.2.0)
; 4. Current working directory (except CLI)
; 5. The web server's directory (for SAPI modules), or directory of PHP
; (otherwise in Windows)
; 6. The directory from the --with-config-file-path compile time option, or the
; Windows directory (C:\windows or C:\winnt)
; See the PHP docs for more specific information.
; http://php.net/configuration.file

; The syntax of the file is extremely simple.  Whitespace and Lines
; beginning with a semicolon are silently ignored (as you probably guessed).
; Section headers (e.g. [Foo]) are also silently ignored, even though
; they might mean something in the future.

; Directives following the section heading [PATH=/www/mysite] only
; apply to PHP files in the /www/mysite directory.  Directives
; following the section heading [HOST=www.example.com] only apply to
; PHP files served from www.example.com.  Directives set in these
; special sections cannot be overridden by user-defined INI files or
; at runtime. Currently, [PATH=] and [HOST=] sections only work under
; CGI/FastCGI.
; http://php.net/ini.sections

; Directives are specified using the following syntax:
; directive = value
; Directive names are *case sensitive* - foo=bar is different from FOO=bar.
; Directives are variables used to configure PHP or PHP extensions.
; There is no name validation.  If PHP can't find an expected
; directive because it is not set or is mistyped, a default value will be used.

; The value can be a string, a number, a PHP constant (e.g. E_ALL or M_PI), one
; of the INI constants (On, Off, True, False, Yes, No and None) or an expression
; (e.g. E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE), a quoted string ("bar"), or a reference to a
; previously set variable or directive (e.g. ${foo})

; Expressions in the INI file are limited to bitwise operators and parentheses:
; |  bitwise OR
; ^  bitwise XOR
; &  bitwise AND
; ~  bitwise NOT
; !  boolean NOT

; Boolean flags can be turned on using the values 1, On, True or Yes.
; They can be turned off using the values 0, Off, False or No.

; An empty string can be denoted by simply not writing anything after the equal
; sign, or by using the None keyword:

;  foo =         ; sets foo to an empty string
;  foo = None    ; sets foo to an empty string
;  foo = "None"  ; sets foo to the string 'None'

; If you use constants in your value, and these constants belong to a
; dynamically loaded extension (either a PHP extension or a Zend extension),
; you may only use these constants *after* the line that loads the extension.

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; About this file ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; PHP comes packaged with two INI files. One that is recommended to be used
; in production environments and one that is recommended to be used in
; development environments.

; php.ini-production contains settings which hold security, performance and
; best practices at its core. But please be aware, these settings may break
; compatibility with older or less security conscience applications. We
; recommending using the production ini in production and testing environments.

; php.ini-development is very similar to its production variant, except it's
; much more verbose when it comes to errors. We recommending using the
; development version only in development environments as errors shown to
; application users can inadvertently leak otherwise secure information.

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Quick Reference ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; The following are all the settings which are different in either the production
; or development versions of the INIs with respect to PHP's default behavior.
; Please see the actual settings later in the document for more details as to why
; we recommend these changes in PHP's behavior.

; allow_call_time_pass_reference
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: Off
;   Production Value: Off

; display_errors
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: Off

; display_startup_errors
;   Default Value: Off
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: Off

; error_reporting
;   Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
;   Development Value: E_ALL | E_STRICT
;   Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED

; html_errors
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: On
;   Production value: Off

; log_errors
;   Default Value: Off
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: On

; magic_quotes_gpc
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: Off
;   Production Value: Off

; max_input_time
;   Default Value: -1 (Unlimited)
;   Development Value: 60 (60 seconds)
;   Production Value: 60 (60 seconds)

; output_buffering
;   Default Value: Off
;   Development Value: 4096
;   Production Value: 4096

; register_argc_argv
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: Off
;   Production Value: Off

; register_long_arrays
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: Off
;   Production Value: Off

; request_order
;   Default Value: None
;   Development Value: "GP"
;   Production Value: "GP"

; session.bug_compat_42
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: Off

; session.bug_compat_warn
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: Off

; session.gc_divisor
;   Default Value: 100
;   Development Value: 1000
;   Production Value: 1000

; session.hash_bits_per_character
;   Default Value: 4
;   Development Value: 5
;   Production Value: 5

; short_open_tag
;   Default Value: On
;   Development Value: Off
;   Production Value: Off

; track_errors
;   Default Value: Off
;   Development Value: On
;   Production Value: Off

; url_rewriter.tags
;   Default Value: "a=href,area=href,frame=src,form=,fieldset="
;   Development Value: "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry"
;   Production Value: "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry"

; variables_order
;   Default Value: "EGPCS"
;   Development Value: "GPCS"
;   Production Value: "GPCS"

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; php.ini Options  ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Name for user-defined php.ini (.htaccess) files. Default is ".user.ini"
;user_ini.filename = ".user.ini"

; To disable this feature set this option to empty value
;user_ini.filename =

; TTL for user-defined php.ini files (time-to-live) in seconds. Default is 300 seconds (5 minutes)
;user_ini.cache_ttl = 300

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Language Options ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Enable the PHP scripting language engine under Apache.
; http://php.net/engine
engine = On

; This directive determines whether or not PHP will recognize code between
; <? and ?> tags as PHP source which should be processed as such. It's been
; recommended for several years that you not use the short tag "short cut" and
; instead to use the full <?php and ?> tag combination. With the wide spread use
; of XML and use of these tags by other languages, the server can become easily
; confused and end up parsing the wrong code in the wrong context. But because
; this short cut has been a feature for such a long time, it's currently still
; supported for backwards compatibility, but we recommend you don't use them.
; Default Value: On
; Development Value: Off
; Production Value: Off
; http://php.net/short-open-tag
short_open_tag = Off

; Allow ASP-style <% %> tags.
; http://php.net/asp-tags
asp_tags = Off

; The number of significant digits displayed in floating point numbers.
; http://php.net/precision
precision = 14

; Enforce year 2000 compliance (will cause problems with non-compliant browsers)
; http://php.net/y2k-compliance
y2k_compliance = On

; Output buffering is a mechanism for controlling how much output data
; (excluding headers and cookies) PHP should keep internally before pushing that
; data to the client. If your application's output exceeds this setting, PHP
; will send that data in chunks of roughly the size you specify.
; Turning on this setting and managing its maximum buffer size can yield some
; interesting side-effects depending on your application and web server.
; You may be able to send headers and cookies after you've already sent output
; through print or echo. You also may see performance benefits if your server is
; emitting less packets due to buffered output versus PHP streaming the output
; as it gets it. On production servers, 4096 bytes is a good setting for performance
; reasons.
; Note: Output buffering can also be controlled via Output Buffering Control
;   functions.
; Possible Values:
;   On = Enabled and buffer is unlimited. (Use with caution)
;   Off = Disabled
;   Integer = Enables the buffer and sets its maximum size in bytes.
; Note: This directive is hardcoded to Off for the CLI SAPI
; Default Value: Off
; Development Value: 4096
; Production Value: 4096
; http://php.net/output-buffering
output_buffering = Off

; You can redirect all of the output of your scripts to a function.  For
; example, if you set output_handler to "mb_output_handler", character
; encoding will be transparently converted to the specified encoding.
; Setting any output handler automatically turns on output buffering.
; Note: People who wrote portable scripts should not depend on this ini
;   directive. Instead, explicitly set the output handler using ob_start().
;   Using this ini directive may cause problems unless you know what script
;   is doing.
; Note: You cannot use both "mb_output_handler" with "ob_iconv_handler"
;   and you cannot use both "ob_gzhandler" and "zlib.output_compression".
; Note: output_handler must be empty if this is set 'On' !!!!
;   Instead you must use zlib.output_handler.
; http://php.net/output-handler
;output_handler =

; Transparent output compression using the zlib library
; Valid values for this option are 'off', 'on', or a specific buffer size
; to be used for compression (default is 4KB)
; Note: Resulting chunk size may vary due to nature of compression. PHP
;   outputs chunks that are few hundreds bytes each as a result of
;   compression. If you prefer a larger chunk size for better
;   performance, enable output_buffering in addition.
; Note: You need to use zlib.output_handler instead of the standard
;   output_handler, or otherwise the output will be corrupted.
; http://php.net/zlib.output-compression
zlib.output_compression = Off

; http://php.net/zlib.output-compression-level
;zlib.output_compression_level = -1

; You cannot specify additional output handlers if zlib.output_compression
; is activated here. This setting does the same as output_handler but in
; a different order.
; http://php.net/zlib.output-handler
;zlib.output_handler =

; Implicit flush tells PHP to tell the output layer to flush itself
; automatically after every output block.  This is equivalent to calling the
; PHP function flush() after each and every call to print() or echo() and each
; and every HTML block.  Turning this option on has serious performance
; implications and is generally recommended for debugging purposes only.
; http://php.net/implicit-flush
; Note: This directive is hardcoded to On for the CLI SAPI
implicit_flush = Off

; The unserialize callback function will be called (with the undefined class'
; name as parameter), if the unserializer finds an undefined class
; which should be instantiated. A warning appears if the specified function is
; not defined, or if the function doesn't include/implement the missing class.
; So only set this entry, if you really want to implement such a
; callback-function.
unserialize_callback_func =

; When floats & doubles are serialized store serialize_precision significant
; digits after the floating point. The default value ensures that when floats
; are decoded with unserialize, the data will remain the same.
serialize_precision = 100

; This directive allows you to enable and disable warnings which PHP will issue
; if you pass a value by reference at function call time. Passing values by
; reference at function call time is a deprecated feature which will be removed
; from PHP at some point in the near future. The acceptable method for passing a
; value by reference to a function is by declaring the reference in the functions
; definition, not at call time. This directive does not disable this feature, it
; only determines whether PHP will warn you about it or not. These warnings
; should enabled in development environments only.
; Default Value: On (Suppress warnings)
; Development Value: Off (Issue warnings)
; Production Value: Off (Issue warnings)
; http://php.net/allow-call-time-pass-reference
allow_call_time_pass_reference = On

; Safe Mode
; http://php.net/safe-mode
safe_mode = Off

; By default, Safe Mode does a UID compare check when
; opening files. If you want to relax this to a GID compare,
; then turn on safe_mode_gid.
; http://php.net/safe-mode-gid
safe_mode_gid = Off

; When safe_mode is on, UID/GID checks are bypassed when
; including files from this directory and its subdirectories.
; (directory must also be in include_path or full path must
; be used when including)
; http://php.net/safe-mode-include-dir
safe_mode_include_dir =

; When safe_mode is on, only executables located in the safe_mode_exec_dir
; will be allowed to be executed via the exec family of functions.
; http://php.net/safe-mode-exec-dir
safe_mode_exec_dir =

; Setting certain environment variables may be a potential security breach.
; This directive contains a comma-delimited list of prefixes.  In Safe Mode,
; the user may only alter environment variables whose names begin with the
; prefixes supplied here.  By default, users will only be able to set
; environment variables that begin with PHP_ (e.g. PHP_FOO=BAR).
; Note:  If this directive is empty, PHP will let the user modify ANY
;   environment variable!
; http://php.net/safe-mode-allowed-env-vars
safe_mode_allowed_env_vars = PHP_

; This directive contains a comma-delimited list of environment variables that
; the end user won't be able to change using putenv().  These variables will be
; protected even if safe_mode_allowed_env_vars is set to allow to change them.
; http://php.net/safe-mode-protected-env-vars
safe_mode_protected_env_vars = LD_LIBRARY_PATH

; open_basedir, if set, limits all file operations to the defined directory
; and below.  This directive makes most sense if used in a per-directory
; or per-virtualhost web server configuration file. This directive is
; *NOT* affected by whether Safe Mode is turned On or Off.
; http://php.net/open-basedir
;open_basedir =

; This directive allows you to disable certain functions for security reasons.
; It receives a comma-delimited list of function names. This directive is
; *NOT* affected by whether Safe Mode is turned On or Off.
; http://php.net/disable-functions
disable_functions =

; This directive allows you to disable certain classes for security reasons.
; It receives a comma-delimited list of class names. This directive is
; *NOT* affected by whether Safe Mode is turned On or Off.
; http://php.net/disable-classes
disable_classes =

; Colors for Syntax Highlighting mode.  Anything that's acceptable in
; <span style="color: ???????"> would work.
; http://php.net/syntax-highlighting
;highlight.string  = #DD0000
;highlight.comment = #FF9900
;highlight.keyword = #007700
;highlight.bg      = #FFFFFF
;highlight.default = #0000BB
;highlight.html    = #000000

; If enabled, the request will be allowed to complete even if the user aborts
; the request. Consider enabling it if executing long requests, which may end up
; being interrupted by the user or a browser timing out. PHP's default behavior
; is to disable this feature.
; http://php.net/ignore-user-abort
;ignore_user_abort = On

; Determines the size of the realpath cache to be used by PHP. This value should
; be increased on systems where PHP opens many files to reflect the quantity of
; the file operations performed.
; http://php.net/realpath-cache-size
;realpath_cache_size = 16k

; Duration of time, in seconds for which to cache realpath information for a given
; file or directory. For systems with rarely changing files, consider increasing this
; value.
; http://php.net/realpath-cache-ttl
;realpath_cache_ttl = 120

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Miscellaneous ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Decides whether PHP may expose the fact that it is installed on the server
; (e.g. by adding its signature to the Web server header).  It is no security
; threat in any way, but it makes it possible to determine whether you use PHP
; on your server or not.
; http://php.net/expose-php
expose_php = On

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Resource Limits ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
; http://php.net/max-execution-time
; Note: This directive is hardcoded to 0 for the CLI SAPI
max_execution_time = 60

; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data. It's a good
; idea to limit this time on productions servers in order to eliminate unexpectedly
; long running scripts.
; Note: This directive is hardcoded to -1 for the CLI SAPI
; Default Value: -1 (Unlimited)
; Development Value: 60 (60 seconds)
; Production Value: 60 (60 seconds)
; http://php.net/max-input-time
max_input_time = 60

; Maximum input variable nesting level
; http://php.net/max-input-nesting-level
;max_input_nesting_level = 64

; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (128MB)
; http://php.net/memory-limit
memory_limit = 128M

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Error handling and logging ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; This directive informs PHP of which errors, warnings and notices you would like
; it to take action for. The recommended way of setting values for this
; directive is through the use of the error level constants and bitwise
; operators. The error level constants are below here for convenience as well as
; some common settings and their meanings.
; By default, PHP is set to take action on all errors, notices and warnings EXCEPT
; those related to E_NOTICE and E_STRICT, which together cover best practices and
; recommended coding standards in PHP. For performance reasons, this is the
; recommend error reporting setting. Your production server shouldn't be wasting
; resources complaining about best practices and coding standards. That's what
; development servers and development settings are for.
; Note: The php.ini-development file has this setting as E_ALL | E_STRICT. This
; means it pretty much reports everything which is exactly what you want during
; development and early testing.
;
; Error Level Constants:
; E_ALL             - All errors and warnings (includes E_STRICT as of PHP 6.0.0)
; E_ERROR           - fatal run-time errors
; E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR  - almost fatal run-time errors
; E_WARNING         - run-time warnings (non-fatal errors)
; E_PARSE           - compile-time parse errors
; E_NOTICE          - run-time notices (these are warnings which often result
;                     from a bug in your code, but it's possible that it was
;                     intentional (e.g., using an uninitialized variable and
;                     relying on the fact it's automatically initialized to an
;                     empty string)
; E_STRICT          - run-time notices, enable to have PHP suggest changes
;                     to your code which will ensure the best interoperability
;                     and forward compatibility of your code
; E_CORE_ERROR      - fatal errors that occur during PHP's initial startup
; E_CORE_WARNING    - warnings (non-fatal errors) that occur during PHP's
;                     initial startup
; E_COMPILE_ERROR   - fatal compile-time errors
; E_COMPILE_WARNING - compile-time warnings (non-fatal errors)
; E_USER_ERROR      - user-generated error message
; E_USER_WARNING    - user-generated warning message
; E_USER_NOTICE     - user-generated notice message
; E_DEPRECATED      - warn about code that will not work in future versions
;                     of PHP
; E_USER_DEPRECATED - user-generated deprecation warnings
;
; Common Values:
;   E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE  (Show all errors, except for notices and coding standards warnings.)
;   E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE | E_STRICT  (Show all errors, except for notices)
;   E_COMPILE_ERROR|E_RECOVERABLE_ERROR|E_ERROR|E_CORE_ERROR  (Show only errors)
;   E_ALL | E_STRICT  (Show all errors, warnings and notices including coding standards.)
; Default Value: E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE
; Development Value: E_ALL | E_STRICT
; Production Value: E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED
; http://php.net/error-reporting
error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED

; This directive controls whether or not and where PHP will output errors,
; notices and warnings too. Error output is very useful during development, but
; it could be very dangerous in production environments. Depending on the code
; which is triggering the error, sensitive information could potentially leak
; out of your application such as database usernames and passwords or worse.
; It's recommended that errors be logged on production servers rather than
; having the errors sent to STDOUT.
; Possible Values:
;   Off = Do not display any errors
;   stderr = Display errors to STDERR (affects only CGI/CLI binaries!)
;   On or stdout = Display errors to STDOUT
; Default Value: On
; Development Value: On
; Production Value: Off
; http://php.net/display-errors
display_errors = On

; The display of errors which occur during PHP's startup sequence are handled
; separately from display_errors. PHP's default behavior is to suppress those
; errors from clients. Turning the display of startup errors on can be useful in
; debugging configuration problems. But, it's strongly recommended that you
; leave this setting off on production servers.
; Default Value: Off
; Development Value: On
; Production Value: Off
; http://php.net/display-startup-errors
display_startup_errors = On

; Besides displaying errors, PHP can also log errors to locations such as a
; server-specific log, STDERR, or a location specified by the error_log
; directive found below. While errors should not be displayed on productions
; servers they should still be monitored and logging is a great way to do that.
; Default Value: Off
; Development Value: On
; Production Value: On
; http://php.net/log-errors
log_errors = Off

; Set maximum length of log_errors. In error_log information about the source is
; added. The default is 1024 and 0 allows to not apply any maximum length at all.
; http://php.net/log-errors-max-len
log_errors_max_len = 1024

; Do not log repeated messages. Repeated errors must occur in same file on same
; line unless ignore_repeated_source is set true.
; http://php.net/ignore-repeated-errors
ignore_repeated_errors = Off

; Ignore source of message when ignoring repeated messages. When this setting
; is On you will not log errors with repeated messages from different files or
; source lines.
; http://php.net/ignore-repeated-source
ignore_repeated_source = Off

; If this parameter is set to Off, then memory leaks will not be shown (on
; stdout or in the log). This has only effect in a debug compile, and if
; error reporting includes E_WARNING in the allowed list
; http://php.net/report-memleaks
report_memleaks = On

; This setting is on by default.
;report_zend_debug = 0

; Store the last error/warning message in $php_errormsg (boolean). Setting this value
; to On can assist in debugging and is appropriate for development servers. It should
; however be disabled on production servers.
; Default Value: Off
; Development Value: On
; Production Value: Off
; http://php.net/track-errors
track_errors = Off

; Turn off normal error reporting and emit XML-RPC error XML
; http://php.net/xmlrpc-errors
;xmlrpc_errors = 0

; An XML-RPC faultCode
;xmlrpc_error_number = 0

; When PHP displays or logs an error, it has the capability of inserting html
; links to documentation related to that error. This directive controls whether
; those HTML links appear in error messages or not. For performance and security
; reasons, it's recommended you disable this on production servers.
; Note: This directive is hardcoded to Off for the CLI SAPI
; Default Value: On
; Development Value: On
; Production value: Off
; http://php.net/html-errors
html_errors = On

; If html_errors is set On PHP produces clickable error messages that direct
; to a page describing the error or function causing the error in detail.
; You can download a copy of the PHP manual from http://php.net/docs
; and change docref_root to the base URL of your local copy including the
; leading '/'. You must also specify the file extension being used including
; the dot. PHP's default behavior is to leave these settings empty.
; Note: Never use this feature for production boxes.
; http://php.net/docref-root
; Examples
;docref_root = "/phpmanual/"

; http://php.net/docref-ext
;docref_ext = .html

; String to output before an error message. PHP's default behavior is to leave
; this setting blank.
; http://php.net/error-prepend-string
; Example:
;error_prepend_string = "<font color=#ff0000>"

; String to output after an error message. PHP's default behavior is to leave
; this setting blank.
; http://php.net/error-append-string
; Example:
;error_append_string = "</font>"

; Log errors to specified file. PHP's default behavior is to leave this value
; empty.
; http://php.net/error-log
; Example:
;error_log = php_errors.log
; Log errors to syslog (Event Log on NT, not valid in Windows 95).
;error_log = syslog
;error_log = "C:\xampp\apache\logs\php_error.log"

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Data Handling ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Note - track_vars is ALWAYS enabled

; The separator used in PHP generated URLs to separate arguments.
; PHP's default setting is "&".
; http://php.net/arg-separator.output
; Example:
arg_separator.output = "&amp;"

; List of separator(s) used by PHP to parse input URLs into variables.
; PHP's default setting is "&
```

Comment: That doesn't appear to be your whole php.ini file.  There's no mention of the xdebug dll, and it appears cut off at the bottom.

Comment: I'd suggest you browse through some of the threads on the right hand side under "Related" as well.  Have you double-checked that you're using the right VC6/VC9 version?  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2403675/xdebug-is-not-loaded-in-php-vista-apache-module

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was looking through php.ini and i Found this line commented out.

```
;zend_extension = "C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug.dll"
```

I believe this is a custom implementation from XAMPP because a) the path is valid b) as soon as i uncommented it i was able to use xdebug!

Success!