# why phpinfo() without xdebug while 'php -v' does in terminal

Tags: php, macos, nginx, homebrew, xdebug

1. In terminal,  'php -v' and show xdebug
   [image: run 'php -v' in terminal]
2. In browser, access phpinfo(), but no xdebug.
   [image]

I had some error codes to see if xdebug works, but it just show error in normal style, no xdebug style.
Q: What is the problem? / How can fixed this?

My web server is Nginx. All of above are installed from homebrew,

so anyone else can help me? THX~

Comment: Please check these link:-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14047152/xdebug-installed-but-does-not-display-in-phpinfo-for-xampp. And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3793390/no-xdebug-in-phpinfo

Comment: Many installations use two different php.ini - one for the console and one for the web server. Perhaps xdebug is enabled in one and not the other. Try running `php --ini` from the console and checking the phpinfo page to see if they are both using the same ini file

Comment: thanks for all of you, it works after restarting my computer